# Select a offset cell in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

im trying to select an offset cell to use as a parameter in a calculation but i dont know how to do it, i want to use the value of the cell itself to calculate, as an exemple replace the "200" in the code. Im trying to use the offset selected to divide and multiply with another cell.

```
Sub teste()

Dim range1 As range
Dim cell As range
Dim NOK, SEK, NZD, EURO As String
    

Set range1 = range("a1:A30")
    
For Each cell In range1

    If cell.Value = "NOK" Then
    
    cell.Offset(0, 1) = 200
    
    ElseIf cell.Value = "NZD" Then
           
    cell.Offset(0, 1) = 300
    
    ElseIf cell.Value = "EURO" Then
    
    cell.Offset(0, 1) = "200" + Worksheets("Planilha2").range("A1")
    
    
    End If


Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `cell.Offset(0, 1) = cell.Offset(0, 1) + Worksheets("Planilha2").range("A1")`

Answer (score -1):

Better, if use `.Value` on Cell Range then you will get the maximum performance like code pasted below.

```
For Each cell In range1

If cell.Value = "NOK" Then

cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 200

ElseIf cell.Value = "NZD" Then
       
cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 300

ElseIf cell.Value = "EURO" Then

cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "200" + Worksheets("Planilha2").Range("A1").Value

End If
```

Next